# Loop through minutes PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to set a variable with a `foreach loop`, every minute.
I have this code:

```
$dhit = 2013-02-07 04:21:01;
$dnow= 2013-02-07 10:21:01;

$begin = new DateTime( $dhit );
$end = new DateTime( $dnow );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString( '1 minute' );
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
$a = 0;
foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
  $a+=1;
  echo $a; 
}
```

It works very well if `$dhit` is at least 24 hours old (2013-02-06 04:21:01) but not if `$dhit` has the same date (same day, i.e. 2013-02-07) of `$dnow`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$dhit = '2013-02-07 10:15:01';` works for me as well and will print out 1-6.

Comment: should this be `$dhit = "2013-02-07 04:21:01";` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me to, i would suspect smth with your system time maybe not being set properly.

What error do you get ?

this is the test i made and it printed 1-360 as expected

```
<?php

$dhit = '2013-02-07 04:21:01';
$dnow= '2013-02-07 10:21:01';

$begin = new DateTime( $dhit );
$end = new DateTime( $dnow );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString( '1 minute' );
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
$a = 0;
foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
  $a+=1;
  print "$a\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Fault was on my server time. I retrieve $dhit and $dnow from a SQL query. Time adjusted, it works! Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me and prints 123456. You forgot to place quotes around your dates.

```
$dhit = '2013-02-07 10:15:01';
$dnow= '2013-02-07 10:21:01';

$begin = new DateTime( $dhit );
$end = new DateTime( $dnow );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString( '1 minute' );
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
$a = 0;
foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
  $a+=1;
  echo $a; //output 123456
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. The error was on my server time. Thank you very much! +1